# Makefile PHONY targets fail using test command

Tags: bash, testing, makefile, target

The following simple PHONY target for Makefile is failing:

```
dir=/etc
file=fstab
install:
        -test ! -f $(dir)/$(file)
```

Error displayed:

```
make install
-I/root/module
test ! -f /etc/fstab
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
```

If I remove the `!` symbol from the condition, there is no issue.
Can someone help me to sort out this issue? I hope this is a bug in bash/Makefile targets.

Comment: Aren't you just getting the exit status of `test`, since `/etc/fstab` most likely exists? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please explain exactly what the issue is.  Then we can help you sort it out.  It looks like everything is working correctly to me.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that. I know that /etc/fstab exists always. But for any file that exits, this check will display the "make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)" error.

Answer (score 0):

Your recipe:

```
-test ! -f $(dir)/$(file)
```

will succeed (return 0) if `$(dir)/$(file)` does not exist and
fail (return non-zero) if `$(dir)/$(file)` exists. Because of the `-`
prefix, make will ignore failure, will by default report that it is ignoring failure, and will carry on
instead of stopping.

Look:

**Makefile**

```
dir=/etc
file=fstab

.PHONY: all install

all: install
    echo "Success"

install:
    -test ! -f $(dir)/$(file)
```

Run it:

```
$ make
test ! -f /etc/fstab
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
echo "Success"
Success
```

`bash` is not broken. `make` is not broken. There is nothing wrong.

If you do not even wish to see `make`'s progess and diagnostic output then
you can silence them:

```
$ make --silent
Success
```

Comment: So that means, the file exists, test command returns 0 and hence the error message(make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No. A command is successful if it returns 0, unsuccessful if it returns
non-0. (This is not a peculiar `make` interpretation: it is the interpretation of Unix-like OSes, their shells, commands and system calls since the start of time.) The `test` command fails, because the file exists, returning 1. Make ignores that error (the return code 1), because of the `-` prefix; it reports that it is ignoring that error, and it carries on.

Comment: How do I run --silent by default?